# Stop Netbeans from Opening Dependency Projects

Tags: maven, netbeans

When opening most of my projects in Netbeans, Netbeans will take the liberty of opening what appear to be most (but not quite all) dependency and transitive dependency projects. Although this seems nice at first, I do not want this behavior; some projects may have 20-50 dependencies.

I've asked a couple of the other guys at work who use Netbeans and they do not have the same issue. So I'm assuming it is a setting that I may have set at sometime in the past and then quickly forgot about it. I cannot find anything suspicious and google isn't helping me much. The behavior is as though I right clicked on the project and selected "Open Required Projects".

I use Maven 3 and projects will only be opened if I have the sources locally and Netbeans already "knows" about the project (ie, I've opened the project in the past).

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not familiar with NetBean's Maven integration so this may be an incomplete answer*

On the right hand side of the Open Project dialog and just under the Project Name text box there are two check boxes. The bottom one reads "Open Required Projects" and if selected will open all of the projects that the selected project requires. From what you're describing, NetBeans is behaving as if this check box has been checked.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Never noticed that before. Not sure how it got checked in the first place but after unchecking it once it remains unchecked.